# Why do my Jenkins / Ant builds always fail?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ant

I'm trying to get Jenkins figured out.  I have a suite of selenium tests that I can build and run via Eclipse or build and run via the command line with ant, but whenever I try Jenkins, they fail.
The console out from Jenkins reports that the value for ws.jars, defined in my build.xml file, doesn't exist; however that directory does exist!  Again, no problem building from the command line.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to get this solved now for a couple of days.

Thanks.

My build.xml file:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="/Users/username/Documents/All JAR Files/All in one place"/>
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>
```

I created a new target in my build.xml file called path.  Here is the output when I run with Jenkins.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/<user>/local_repo/qa-automation/selenium-java/my-projects
[my-projects] $ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Install_automatically/bin/ant path
Buildfile: /Users/<user>/local_repo/qa-automation/selenium-java/my-projects/build.xml
path:
 [echo] 
 [echo]                 My path - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
 [echo] 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: 1) could you provide the section in build.xml where you declare  the jars ?

Comment: are you running in windows / linux ? could it be an access user permission, remember that usually your jenkins setup will use the Jenkins user

Comment: I am running in OS X.  I tried changing the owner of the ws.jars directory to jenkins, but got the same error.

Comment: Can you echo the PATH or write your environment variables? When Jenkins runs a job on an executor (either on a slave or master) it executes the job inside a non-interactive shell script in */bin/sh*, not as login shell in */bin/bash*. This means that you get a smaller set of environment variables than what your would get from command line. If that is the case I might have a solution.

Comment: Sure. I created a new target in my build.xml file called path.  I added to my original post.  I like where this is going.  I noticed my my jre is in there 2x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your suggestions.  I hadn't thought about this in awhile but last night I had some time and was able to work on this issue again.  Turns out it was related to the Jenkins job being executed in the non-interactive shell, just as 'rgulia' pointed out.  So finally, I tried copying my ws.jars directory to /Users/Shared/Jenkins, changed the owner to 'jenkins', and boom, my build was able to proceed.
The original error message was just so misleading.  It wasn't that the directory didn't exist, but that 'jenkins' didn't have access and/or permissions to it. 
I hope this information can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is caused by the spaces within your path of `ws.jars`. You should escape these spaces by adding `\`, try change the path :

```
<property name="ws.jars" value="/Users/username/Documents/All JAR Files/All in one place"/>
```

with this one:

```
<property name="ws.jars" value="/Users/username/Documents/All\ JAR\ Files/All\ in\ one\ place/"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I already tried that and it made no difference.

Comment: I've even tried creating a new directory with no spaces and modified my build.xml to point to it.  Still no dice.
/Users/username/Documents/All-in-one-place